# <asp:login id:login1 is not defined in default.aspx.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms

I am making a login page to test encryption methods on xml files but i am stuck right now at this problem.
I have a login with an ID login1 inside my default.aspx like this:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/RoseindiaMaster.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default" %>

<asp:Content id="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content id="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
    <div>
        <h2 style="color: Green">
            Login using Xml file in ASP.NET 4, C#</h2>
        <asp:Login id="Login1" runat="Server" BackColor="#F7F7DE" BorderColor="#CCCC99" BorderStyle="Solid"
            BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="10pt" Height="166px" OnAuthenticate="Login1_Authenticate"
            Width="264px" FailureText="Username and password did not match!">
            <TitleTextStyle BackColor="#6B696B" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#FFFFFF" />
        </asp:Login>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

but inside my default.aspx.cs i cant use login1 i get the error: `The name 'Login1' does not exist in current context`

```cs
protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
    {
        string username;
        string pwd;
        string CurrentUser = "";
        string CurrentPwd = "";
        bool LoginStatus = false;
        username = Login1.UserName;
        pwd = Login1.Password;
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing the `CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs"` to `CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs`